# How can I use python code in with_entities() of sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My code is like this:

```py
status_dict = {
    0: 'ready',
    1: 'downloading',
    2: 'downloaded',
}


class Videos(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'videos'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0, index=True)


class Test:

    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        videos = Videos.query.with_entities(
            Videos.id.label('vid'),
            Videos.status,
            some_func(status_dict[Videos.status]).label('status_desc')
        ).order_by(
            Videos.id.desc()
        ).all()

        rows = qs2json(videos)
```

I want to achieve an effect like this:

```json
[
    {
        "vid": 103,
        "status": 0,
        "status_desc": "ready",
    },
    {
        "vid": 102,
        "status": 1,
        "status_desc": "downloading",
    },
    {
        "vid": 101,
        "status": 2,
        "status_desc": "downloaded",
    }
]
```

I've achieved the function qs2json(), but what is the function `some_func` in SQLAlchemy?

### I tried some functions in SQLAlchemy, but I met Errors <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object ...

---

I made a customed python function like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import GenericFunction, func
from sqlalchemy.types import String


class MyFuncs(GenericFunction):
    type = String

    def get_status_desc(self, status):
        return status_dict[status]


class Test:

    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        videos = Videos.query.with_entities(
            Videos.id.label('vid'),
            Videos.status,
            func.MyFuncs.get_status_desc(Videos.status).label('status_desc')
        ).order_by(
            Videos.id.desc()
        ).all()
```

And I met with `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1305, 'FUNCTION MyFuncs.get_status_desc does not exist')`

Answer (score 0):

Use [case](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=case#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) for this, for your example:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
class Videos(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'videos'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0, index=True)

    @classmethod
    def as_dict(cls, obj):
        return dict(obj)


videos = Videos.query.with_entities(
    Videos.id.label('vid'),
    Videos.status,
    sa.case([(Videos.status == k, v) for k, v in status_dict.items()]).label('status_desc')
).order_by(
    Videos.id.desc()
).all()

json_data = json.dumps([Videos.as_dict(v) for v in videos])

print(json_data)
# [{"vid": 3, "status": 1, "status_desc": "downloading"}, {"vid": 2, "status": 2, "status_desc": "downloaded"}, {"vid":
# 1, "status": 0, "status_desc": "ready"}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It works! But, it is not the exact answer which I want. I wonder is there a function in SQLAlchemy allows me to put a python function or some python value in the `some_func` function. If I need a python func to figure out the value to `.label('some_label')`

Comment: Not just python function, but you could try to use [func](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/functions.html#sql-and-generic-functions) or even write your own using  [GenericFunction](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.GenericFunction)

Comment: I edited my question and I met with error. I don't quite understand [GenericFunction](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.GenericFunction)
for its example is not detailed enough, and I found little about it  on the Internet. Would you please do me a favor to give a correct example of the class `MyFuncs` ?

Comment: This won't work, because it's impossible to convert your function directly into SQL, see what func module supports: count, min, max, coalesce etc. All of them are supported by the database itself. I believe technically it's possible to implement your own such function (which can be used in sql), but it's really overengineering in your case. Just use *case,* it's a right way here